Using trigonometric substitutions to simplify quartic roots expressions
I read this paper and I am particularly interested in the result in appendix A. While working on the quartic polynomial:
$$ q_1(p) = p^4 - \kappa (\lambda_2 \xi)^4 p + (\lambda_2 \xi)^4$$
The author manages to write its roots $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ in a very coincise form.
$$p= \mp \lambda_2 \alpha \sqrt{\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{3}}} \left( \pm  1 (\pm) i \sqrt{1 \pm \sqrt{a_2}}\right)$$
$$a_1  = \begin{cases} \cos (\theta / 3) & 0 \leq \eta < 1 \\
            \cosh (\theta / 3) & 1 \leq 1 \eta  \\
        \end{cases} $$
$$a_2  = \begin{cases} \frac{\eta}{\cos^3 (\theta / 3)} & 0 \leq \eta < 1 \\
            \frac{\eta}{\cosh^3 (\theta / 3)} & 1 \leq 1 \eta  \\
        \end{cases} $$
$$\eta  = 3 \sqrt{3} \left(\frac{\kappa \lambda_2 \alpha}{4}\right)^2 $$
$$\theta = arccos (\eta)$$
What is better, this form works wonderfully for computation of numerical values of the roots even for very large values of $\xi$. For reference, the parameters are $\lambda_2,\kappa \in ]0,10]$. He claims to be using the method from this book, but he makes some clever substitutions (being the use of trigonometric quantities). Basically, when looking for a real root of the solving cubic:
$$ u^3 - 4 (\lambda_2 \xi)^4 u - \kappa^2 (\lambda_2 \xi)^8 = 0 $$
the author uses $\eta$ to rewrite its discriminant as $D = \eta^4 - 1$ and the cubic root as:
$$ u = s_1 + s_2$$
$$ s_{1,2}^3 = \frac{2^3}{\sqrt{3^3}}(\lambda_2 \alpha)^6 \left(\eta  \pm \sqrt{\eta^2 - 1}\right) $$
Which then allows to introduce the variable $\theta$ and use trigonometric substitutions.
I am working with more complicated quartics, like:
$$q_2(p) = p^4 - \kappa \lambda_2^4 p^3 + \lambda_2^4 (1 - 2 \kappa \alpha^2) p^2 + \lambda_2^4(2 \alpha^2 - \kappa \alpha^4) p + \lambda_2^4 \alpha^4$$
For which the closed form solutions with nested radicals are not giving sound numerical results. I believe the issue is in the powers of $\alpha$ which go up to $\alpha^{10}$ under the roots. My question is if this method of ``normalizing'' the discriminant is a known approach and has been generalized for complete quartics like $q_2$, or if it is a case specific tool.

@George Plousos The link you have given is considered as potentialy dangerous by my anti-virus software.

There is a trigonometric method of solving the quartic equation but for now it can be applied to a specific class of equations (see description): https://gr.pinterest.com/pin/942167184543081774/
